# Using multiple parameters in an XQuery?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

I have the following `Java` Method that uses `XQuery`:

```
 public String getLocationByName(String name) {
            final String nameToQueryFor = name;
            return engine.new Query<String>(MY_COLLECTION) {

                @Override
                protected String query(Collection collection) throws Exception {
                    XQueryService service = queryService();

                    ResourceSet resourceSet = service.query(
                            format("//Products/Product[name='%s']" +
                                            "/attribute"
                                    , StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(nameToQueryFor)
                            ));

                    List<String> results = newArrayList();

                    for (String resource : new IterableStringResources(resourceSet)) {
                        results.add(resource);
                    }
                    return results.get(0);
                }
            }.execute();
        }
```

As can be seen I currently am only querying using one parameter, i.e. `name`.

I am a beginner with XQuery, How can I alter this Xquery to take an additional parameter: `price`

My method would now become:

```
 public String getLocationByNameAndPrice(String name)
```

Comment: Also note that it might be safer and easier to use  http://exist-db.org/api/org/exist/xmldb/XQueryService.html#declareVariable(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object) to set up variables for your Query so that you can then use `//Products/Product[name=$name]` instead of string formatting and concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the condition into your XPath, e.g.:

```
format("//Products/Product[name='%s' and price='%s']/attribute",
  StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(nameToQueryFor),
  StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(priceToQueryFor))
```

The exact syntax of the query of course depends on your XML document.